# PowerShell - Unzip large archives - Runspace Factory

Tags: powershell, runspace

I am using the below PowerShell code to extract the contents of a zip file. It's part of a larger workflow script. These zips are on average 3 GB expanding to up to 25 GB size and take a few minutes to complete the expansion operation.

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$Shell.Namespace($ExtractionFolder).copyhere($Shell.NameSpace($InputZipFile).Items(),0x14)
```

On its own, it works as expected. However, I use this workflow script through PowerShell Runspace factory so I could run more than one instance for batch processing.

With the multi-threaded runspace option, the first instance starts and continues with the expansion without any issues however for the second instance and more, the above command returns immediately without the expansion. It looks as though the Windows shell subsystem does not allow more than one expansion at the same time (though I could be wrong).

Could you let me know if there is a cleverer way to address this? Thanks.

NB. The zip format being used does not work with standard Expand-Archive cmdlet.

Comment: Can't you use [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or similar to unpack those large files? Also, when creating COM objects, you should release them from memory when done. If you don't, the system will run out of memory quite fast..

Comment: 7-zip workaround is brilliant. It's faster too. And no COMObjecting business. Thanks.